# sqlite ошибка near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

Готовя функцию для более простой работой с sqlite, встретил не особо понятную мне ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\py\bot2.py", line 46, in <module>
    update_database(set_name = "coin", value_name = "123", where_name = "294627349")
  File "C:\python\py\bot2.py", line 32, in update_database
    cursor.execute("UPDATE (?) SET (?) = (?) WHERE (?) = (?)", (table_name, set_name, value_name, where_who, where_name) )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Вот сама функция и то, что я на неё подаю:

```
def update_database(set_name, value_name, where_name, table_name = "num", where_who = "id"):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE (?) SET (?) = (?) WHERE (?) = (?)", (table_name, set_name, value_name, where_who, where_name) )
    sqlite_connection.commit()

update_database(set_name = "coin", value_name = "123", where_name = "294627349")
```

Почему так происходит? Хотя оно работает в более простых вариантах, по типу таких:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE num SET coin = (?) WHERE id = ?", (coin_value, id_value))
```

Comment: Последний вариант отличается от первого тем, что имена таблицы и столбцов не обернуто в скобки, на которые и ругается SQLite.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов я пробовал убирать скобки из имён таблицы и столбцов, так получается примерно такая же ошибка: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\py\bot2.py", line 47, in <module>
    update_database(set_name = "coin", value_name = "123", where_name = "294627349")
  File "C:\python\py\bot2.py", line 32, in update_database
    cursor.execute("UPDATE ? SET ? = (?) WHERE (?) = (?)", (table_name, set_name, value_name, where_who, where_name) )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`.

Возможно ли вообще сделать имя таблицы и/или столбцов из переменной?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsqlite%5D+%5Bpython%5D+escape+table+name

Comment: Параметризовать можно только _значения_. Имена таблиц и столбцов невозможно задать в виде _параметров_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется нашёл костыль, который работает - передавать значение с помощью списка, а названия через f-строку. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
def update_database(set_name, value_name, where_name, table_name = "num", where_who = "id"):
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE {table_name} SET {set_name} = (?) WHERE {where_who} = (?)", (value_name, where_name))
    sqlite_connection.commit()
```

Хоть выглядит довольно странно, но работает

Comment: Учтите две вещи. 1 - в имени таблицы/поля могут быть не-А символы (скажем, пробел), т.е. имена надо квотировать; 2 - в имени поля могут присутствовать символы, которые использованы для квотирования - такие символы надо экранировать.